# Creating MySQL a table with a primary text key

Tags: mysql

The command that I use to `CREATE` my `TABLE` is:

```
CREATE TABLE carts(order_id TEXT(14), items TEXT, shipping INT, price INT
```

I'd like to set 'order_id' as my primary key. I've tried to `ALTER` the `TABLE` with:

```
ALTER TABLE `carts` ADD PRIMARY KEY(order_id)
```

But that returns the error:

```
 #1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'order_id' used in key specification without a key length
```

I understand that means that the length isn't being set correctly in the initial setup, so I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE `carts` ADD PRIMARY KEY(order_id(14))
```

Which returns the same error. The type defined in *phpmyadmin* is 'tinytext'; I was expecting to see `TEXT(14)`.

I'm performing all of these commands via PDO in PHP. What's the correct way to set the column 'order_id' as my `TABLE`'s primary key?

Comment: Change `text` to `varchar`. you can't set a text as a primary key.

Comment: You can't use a `TEXT` data type as a primary key.

Comment: Your last statement is well, it will create primary key with length 14. So what's the error?

Comment: `order_id`  TEXT??  If your order_id are characters please make it a `VARCHAR` Don't use TEXT for this.

Comment: Why aren't you using VARCHAR as data type for ordeR_id column? There is a restriction on creating indexes for TEXT/LOB data types in MySQL and that is why you're getting the error

Comment: the table i was using require the id to be more than 20 character for which i was force to choose text and its working fine but I want to know if this is stable and reliable as the id is not autoincrement but timestamp(milisecond) and some other postfix added for info purposes.

Answer (score 10):

in MySQL `BLOB/TEXT` are not served as a part of table, rather they are referenced from other memory locations. So they cannot be treated as a part of `KEY`.

You have to define it as VARCHAR(14).

```
ALTER TABLE `carts` modify order_id VARCHAR(14);
```

And then you can apply the PK.

```
ALTER TABLE `carts` ADD PRIMARY KEY(order_id);
```